# Is at a good idea to use ThreadPoolExecutor with one worker?

Tags: python-3.x, multithreading, python-multiprocessing, python-multithreading, threadpoolexecutor

I have a simple rest service which allows you to create task. When a client requests a task - it returns a unique task number and starts executing in a separate thread. The easiest way to implement it

```
class Executor:
    def __init__(self, max_workers=1):
        self.executor = ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers)

    def execute(self, body, task_number):
        # some logic
        pass

def some_rest_method(request):
    body = json.loads(request.body)
    task_id = generate_task_id()
    Executor(max_workers=1).execute(body)
    return Response({'taskId': task_id})
```

Is it a good idea to create each time ThreadPoolExecutor with one (!) workers if i know than one request - is one new task (new thread). Perhaps it is worth putting them in the queue somehow? Maybe the best option is to create a regular stream every time?

Comment: Your example looks like it _might_ have a serious bug. It returns the `Response(...)` without waiting for the "separate thread" to finish processing the request. It could even happen before the separate thread even _begins_ to process the request.  Is that what you meant for it to do? If not, then probably the best way to fix it is to have the thread return the `Response(...)`

Comment: Oh, sorry, of course not. Wrote about my problem below in the comment

Answer (score 2):

> Is it a good idea to create each time ThreadPoolExecutor...

No. That completely defeats the purpose of a thread pool.  The reason for using a thread pool is so that you *don't* create and destroy a new thread for every request.  Creating and destroying threads is expensive.  The idea of a thread pool is that it keeps the "worker thread(s)" alive and re-uses it/them for each next request.

> ...with just one thread

There's a good use-case for a single-threaded executor, though it probably does not apply to your problem.  The use-case is, you need a sequence of tasks to be performed "in the background," but you also need them to be performed sequentially.  A single-thread executor will perform the tasks, one after another, in the same order that they were submitted.

> Perhaps it is worth putting them in the queue somehow?

You already *are* putting them in a queue. Every thread pool has a queue of pending tasks. When you submit a task (i.e., `executor.execute(...)`) that puts the task into the queue.

---

> what's the best way...in my case?

The bones of a simplistic server look something like this (pseudo-code):

```
POOL = ThreadPoolExecutor(...with however many threads seem appropriate...)

def service():
    socket = create_a_socket_that_listens_on_whatever_port()
    while True:
        client_connection = socket.accept()
        POOL.submit(request_handler, connection=connection)

def request_handler(connection):
    request = receive_request_from(connection)
    reply = generate_reply_based_on(request)
    send_reply_to(reply, connection)
    connection.close()

def main():
    initialize_stuff()
    service()
```

Of course, there are many details that I have left out. I can't design it for you. Especially not in Python. I've written servers like this in other languages, but I'm pretty new to Python.

Comment: and what's the best way to use threads in my case? I have one rest method which gives the client a unique taskId and starts the task execution. And client polls the task status by taskId until it is completed. As soon as it completes - he requests a body. How to implement it correctly if there are many clients?